# Can I clone a MacBook to another one and work with both without annoyances?

Tags: macbook-pro, carbon-copy-cloner

I have an old MacBook MacBook4,1 (named Mac1) under Lion. My daughter is working with it.
I have just bought another old MacBook2,1 (named Mac2) which is under Snow Leopard and that I need to reinstall completely.

Can I make a clone of the first one and use this clone on the second one ?

Mac1 has already two profiles, one for me and one for her. So I presume the clone installed on Mac2 would have the same.

But if two computers have exactly the same settings, will it make issues with iCloud or whatever programs which may think each computer is not unique ?

If I cannot to do that, what is the best method to reinstall a Snow Leopard without the CD or DVD ?  Is it the Internet Recovery system ?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question adding explicit and specific hardware information about the two Mac's, e.g, MacBook 13" Late 2008, Model Identifier MacBook4,1, which you can get from Apple menu > About this Mac and then More Info...

Comment: done .. I have checked of course that both can have Lion

Comment: There are two different MacBook's for each of those Model Identifiers, which is why I also asks you include, e.g. MacBook 13" Late 2008.